# Determining formula for linear operator on the basis of eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Problem:** Determine an explicit formula for the linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with eigenvalues $1, 2$ and $3$ corresponding to the eigenvectors $(2,-1,0), (-1,2,-1)$ and $(0,-1,2)$.

**Attempt at solution:** I'm not sure how to do this. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$, we have $T(v) =\lambda v$ per definition. So in these cases we have \begin{align*} T \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 1 \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\  T \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 4 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix} \\ T \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = 3 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Now I wrote down a general formule like this: \begin{align*} T \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax + by + cz \\ dx + ey + fz \\ gx + hy + iz \end{pmatrix} \end{align*} For the first eigenvector I get the following equation then: \begin{align*} T \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2a - b \\ 2d - e \\ 2g - h \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*} I applied the same method for the other two vectors, and then I got 3 systems of equations I had to solve. I'm not sure if this is the right way. Is there a better and much faster approach to this problem?

Comment: Your approach will work. You could also start with the diagonal matrix with $1, 2, 3$ on the diagonal and use a change of basis  matrix.

Comment: What do you mean? If I let $D$ be the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal, then I need to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} A P = D$? What should I pick as $A$ then?

Comment: I'll post a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the matrix $D = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{array}\right)$ has the desired eigenvalues, but its corresponding eigenvectors are not what we want. $(1, 0, 0)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, for instance. However, this is easy to fix. We can just change the basis to suit our needs (an explanation of why this works can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis)).

Set $P = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}2&-1&0\\-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2\end{array}\right)$. It has the desired eigenvectors as its columns. Thus $P (1, 0, 0)^T = (2, -1, 0)^T$, etc. Consider the matrix $A=PDP^{-1}$. I claim that $A$ has the desired properties. For instance, $$A (2, -1, 0)^T = PDP^{-1} (2, -1, 0)^T = PD (1, 0, 0)^T = P (1, 0, 0)^T = (2, -1, 0)^T$$ Similarly, the other two vectors are eigenvectors of $A$ with the desired eigenvalues.

Comment: I see, thanks. I have two questions. 1) They are asking for an explicit formula for $T$, but we have found $A$. Should we then just use $L_A$, I mean: $L_A (x, y, z)^T = A (x, y, z)^T$ and then we would get the explicit formula? 2) To use the formula $A = P D P^{-1}$ didn't we need to know that the linear transformation $T$ is diagonalizable? How could we know that? Because the eigenvalues are distinct?

Comment: 1) Giving a matrix is the same as giving an explicit formula for a linear transformation. So yes, your $L_A$ is correct. 2) All I've done here is come up with a matrix which has the desired properties. I didn't need special permission to multiply the matrices $P, D,$ and $P^{-1}$ together. But when I do, it turns out I get the matrix I was looking for. In this case, by construction, $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix. I didn't need to know that it would end up being so at the beginning of my argument though.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same idea as in the attempt, but in more terse form. Since $T v_i = \lambda_i v_i$, we can write it as
$$
T \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & v_3\end{pmatrix}}_{=X} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 v_1 & \lambda_2 v_2 & \lambda_3 v_3\end{pmatrix}}_{=Y},
$$
so $T = Y X^{-1}$.

Comment: The reasoning here is logically equivalent to the reasoning in my answer, but this is perhaps easier to "see."